# Loading content into a container div from a button within using jquery

Tags: jquery-load

This is just a test of something I'm trying to accomplish here that is probably incredibly simple but is racking my brain. I've reviewed some of the closest matches already available here, but I wasn't able to make any of them work.

I'm trying to load content into a div using a button, like so:

```
<div class="load-container">
  <button class="load-first">Load First</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".load-first").click(function() { $(".load-container").load("/test-1.html"); });
 $(".load-second").click(function() { $(".load-container").load("/test-2.html"); });
 $(".load-third").click(function() { $(".load-container").load("/test-3.html"); });
</script>
```

And this actually works on the first try, but then, when "/test-1.html" loads, the next button doesn't work. This is what is in /test-1.html file:

```
This is the first one.<br>
<button class="load-second">Load Second</button>
```

Clicking the second button should load the next bit of content but it does nothing. Is the problem that the button is inside of the destination container div? I need a container div with buttons inside that can load new content in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because at the time the page is loaded, the "load-second" button was not there yet, thus the click() event was not registered to the button that is yet to come via the load() content, you need to attach your event after your buttons are created in the DOM, try the following:

```
<div class="load-container">
  <button class="load-first">Load First</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(".load-first").click(function() { 
        $(".load-container").load("/test-1.html", function(){  
        // now load-second button is available, register the click handler
        $(".load-second").click(function() { 
            $(".load-container").load("/test-2.html", function(){
            // now load-third button is available, register the click handler
            $(".load-third").click(function() { $(".load-container").load("/test-3.html"); });
            });
        });
       });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Forgive my inexperience, you answer seems to make sense but what you provided doesn't appear to work after loading the first /test-1.html which is what it did before. The button inside of /test-1.html doesn't work once it is loaded into .load-container.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code to use the callback of the load() function as you could pass a callback function in the 2nd parameter of the load() function to be executed after the content is loaded, this will make sure the click event registration is executed after the content is loaded.

Comment: Excellent, you could close the question by marking this solution as the answer.